# Default Chinese Characters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, fonts, ssrs-2008-r2

We use SSRS (2008 R2) to present data from several languages. We use labels with the Arial font. If the characters loaded from the database cannot be presented by Arial, SSRS converts them automatically to the relevant font that includes the special characters.
It works well with several languages. However, with Chinese the default choice of SSRS is font MingLiu. This font is quite uncommon in mainland China and the locals say that it is unusable. I would like to use the SimSun font instead.
How do I configure SSRS to force SimSun instead of MingLiu? Of course, I can create new labels with the SimSun font, but that will require recreation of all the existing reports that are already configured with Arial.

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting SSRS to use MingLiu for Chinese characters? 

And why can't you just change that to use SimSun instead?

Comment: I do not know how SSRS chooses to use MingLiu, I think it has to be a default setting of SSRS or Windows. If I knew where this setting is (if it exists) I could change it.

Comment: Try using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial_Unicode_MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My boss found a solution to force the SimSun font:

1. Each one of the report's Placeholder should be configured as HTML.
   This is done via the placeholder's properties / General, and then
   choose "HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles" instead of the default
   "None - Plain text only"
2. The value to be assigned to the placeholder should
   include the HTML tags to force the SimSun font. For example: `<font face="SimSun">订单确认</font>`

Comment: **To increase the size:** `<font face="SimSun" size="+3">订单确认</font>`

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the field value for which you want Chinese Characters in your table. It will display the Placeholder Properties window. Or else right click on the field value & select Placeholder Properties option. In the Placeholder Properties window under the General tab select 'HTML - Interpret HTML tags as styles' radio button. Click OK.

[image: Placholder Properties window]

Then open the code (XML) of the .rdl file. Add the `<FontFamily>SimSun</FontFamily>` tag under the `<Style>` tag of the relevant field value for which you want Chinese characters.

[image: XML code]

Finally close Report Builder & re-open it. Now it will display Chinese characters in the given field when the report is rendered.